# How to clean fabric-covered light cord

Tags: cleaning, home, cables

We just hung some pendant lamps that are suspended by the electrical cord. The cord is covered in white fabric that unfortunately got dirty during the mounting process. What's a good way to try to clean this without taking the whole thing down?

[image: Hanging lamp with fabric cord]

Comment: What kind of fabric is it? Cotton, woven nylon, something else?

Comment: @MiG I'm not sure, but I'd say it's something similar to loosely woven cotton. It's on the softer side and can be easily compressed when one end of the cable is cut.

Comment: My first thought cleaning wise was using **wash benzene** (which is excellent drawing dirt out if you just hold the sheath bit by bit in a small soaked cloth), however I'm still not 100% convinced it's 1. not nylon and 2. that if it is, it wouldn't get affected.

Comment: @MiG Yeah, I definitely can't guarantee the makeup of the fabric

Comment: There's the ending of the sheath that disappears into the fixture, you could apply some wash benzene there and see if it does any damage?

Comment: Do the individual strands seem bristly to you or do they curl up easily?

Comment: @MiG Neither? They're soft and pliable. I'm not sure what you mean when asking if they curl up easily.

Comment: Trying to figure out the material by its properties. I'd say that's probably cotton then, so wash benzene is an option. Try to dab it at first, if you soak it right away it'll transport the dirt (assuming it's greasy) and create a ring that propagates upward and downward from the cleaning spot.

Comment: Would a lint remover help? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lint_remover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The "Love it and leave it… aka single-guy" Lifehack:**

It's difficult since this issue is now 'top-of-mind' after you've noticed it.

**Ignore it**. In a short time (YMMV) you'll forget about it and nooooobody will notice it. Other more urgent issues with the decor and with life in general will take centre-stage.

Good luck.

Comment: As much as I hate it, it seems this will be our likely solution. I tried the Magic Eraser and it was not super effective.

Comment: @DavidK I'm sorry it didn't work out as you wished it had.

Answer (score 1):

**It's only a flesh wound Lifehack:**

If everything has been dry, there's a better than average chance that the dirt on the cord cover is superficial from the hands of a careless handyman/electrician.

First try:

A stiff brush or plastic scrubber might be used to lightly (but briskly) whisk/buff the grime off the surface of the cord.

No? Then, go to the next level:

Use a little "magic™" *cleaning solution*… 
—made from 1 tsp borax (sodium tetraborate) and 3 tsp baking soda (sodium bicarbonate) dissolved in half-a-cup of warm water— to remove any remaining dross.

Here's how:

- Soak a melamine sponge with the solution, squeeze excess liquid free = a DIY "magic eraser.")
- Use the moistened closed-cell "eraser" to lightly clean the cord surface

No? Then, go to the next level

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

**The Quick <strike>'n Dirty</strike> Lamp-cord Fabric Sheath Whitener Lifehack:**

**Liquid Shoe Whitener** with its own self-applicator would be a cover-up that would probably work well for you.

The brand I'm thinking of has a small wingless bird from New Zealand as its trade-mark. I don't recall the name. It comes in a small plastic bottle. I remember it worked wonders for nurses' shoes, running shoes, great stuff and easy to apply.

Tips:

- You'll want to dab some of the stuff onto a scrap and let it dry to compare the result with *your* decor to see if this 'works.'
- Cover anything under your work to avoid drips which would look horrible on the lampshade… or the table under it… or the rug under it… or the floor under it.

Good Luck.

Comment: So you're effectively suggesting to paint it white

Comment: You're probably thinking of Kiwi.  But you got the name of your island a bit off... the Kiwi is typically associated with New Zealand, not Australia.  See https://theculturetrip.com/pacific/new-zealand/articles/why-are-new-zealanders-called-kiwis/

Comment: The shade of white produced by this whitener may be different from the original lamp cord though, so it might stand out from the base and the fixture afterward.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you succeed in cleaning the cord now, it will need doing again at regular intervals, from occasional spider mess, air-borne dirt, fondues, etc. Nobody really looks at light cords anyway and this fabric covering is a recipe to attract the eye when it becomes soiled again.

My hack is to **remove the fabric covering** completely. Cleaning it in the future will be easy: a quick wipe with a damp cloth.

Comment: This isn't a bad suggestion but won't work in my case. Underneath the fabric covering is clear plastic cable containing three other wires within it, so that would look much worse IMO

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap white electrical tape around the cord which would give it an easy to clean surface instead of the cloth.